# Where to find missing dependencies (imagemagick and m17n)

Tags: compilation, debian

I am compiling Emacs from source and can't figure out what libraries I need to enable [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) and [m17n](http://www.nongnu.org/m17n/). I have imagemagick and libm17n-dev installed (I am on Debian).

My `./configure` script says:

```
  Does Emacs use imagemagick?                             no
  [...]
  Does Emacs use -lm17n-flt?                              no
```

Comment: We need more information. You should look at the **config.log** file that contains details and results about the tests that the configure script ran. Search for imagemagick and m17n-flt. Post details on the failing tests or the cut out sections of the log.

Comment: I have installed libmagickcore-dev and libmagick++-dev, and now configure finds imagemagick.
Still no luck with m17n-flt (no such package on debian).

Comment: What Debian version are you on? `m17n-flt` [is part of `libm17n`](http://www.nongnu.org/m17n/manual-en/group__m17nIntro.html) and the [headers are included in `libm17n-dev`](http://pkgs.org/debian-wheezy/debian-main-amd64/libm17n-dev_1.6.3-2_amd64.deb.html).

Comment: The safest procedure to solve dependency issues when compiling from source (including Git) is to run `apt-get build-dep emacs24`, or if you're using Wheezy, `apt-get build-dep emacs23`. That should install all dependency packages and solve the issue. If you're planning to compile Emacs 24.4 or higher, check that the `libacl1-dev` package has been installed, otherwise you'll need to install it manually.

Answer (score 8):

After crawling the `configure` script, I think I have found your missing packet:
**`libmagickwand-dev`**. On my machine, after installing this packet, `./configure` finally says:

```
  Does Emacs use imagemagick?                             yes
```

---

NB1: as with other features (eg `libxml2-dev` for eww), I do not get the purpose of `--with-feature`:

- If the libraries and development headers are on your system, `configure` will enable the feature even if you do not explicitly ask `--with-feature`;
- If the libraries and development headers are not on your system, `configure` will ignore `--with-feature` and exit with status 0.

NB2: This has been tested on Ubuntu 14.04; [libmagickwand-dev](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/libmagickwand-dev) seems to exist in Debian too.

NB3: A general "methodology" to figure out the necessary packages from the
`configure` script:

- search `configure` for "imagemagick"
- find these snippets:

  ```
  IMAGEMAGICK_MODULE="Wand >= 6.3.5 Wand != 6.8.2"
  ...
  if "$PKG_CONFIG" --exists "$IMAGEMAGICK_MODULE"...
  ```
- `apt-cache search Wand`

  - ⇒ `libmagickwand-dev - image manipulation library - development files`

Answer (score 6):

To avoid having to track down the packages that are required to build Emacs, use apt-get to install them for you.

```
apt-get build-dep emacs
```

Actually this may not be enough, as this just installs the libraries the Debian maintainer has chosen to link Emacs against. I think you need:

```
apt-get install libm17n-dev libmagickcore-dev
```

However after this I still got `use -lm17n-flt? no` even when I explicitly used `--with-m17n-flt`. And I did not actually install libmagickcore-dev` because it resulted in a conflict.

Comment: This just turns a comment from above into an answer.

Answer (score 1):

As the [existing](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/7506/8516) answer leaves out how to compile with `m17n` support, I add this to answer that. In my system `m17n` is not used and `otf` is also not used. To build with `m17n` support, install libraries needed for `m17n` and also for `otf`. Then Emacs will be compiled with both of them.

I don't know why compiling with `m17n` requires `otf` but this works :)

Comment: What libraries are needed for m17n and otf?